# Google Chrome not loading javascript files on first load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I have an application that hosts its own webserver.

When I try to access this server from a brand new computer, with a brand new chrome installation (so that nothing is cached from previous access), not all the JavaScript files are loaded, so the website doesn't work properly.

However, if I do a `Ctrl+Shift+R` everything is loaded and everything works just fine.

Had I accessed the site before I would have suspected some caching, but because this is a new installation of chrome there shouldn't have been anything cached in the first place.

I'm not sure how to go about finding anything about this, because all search results are about Chrome already having cached a file, which is not the case for me.

Does anybody have any ideas on what can cause Chrome to not load everything correctly when there is nothing in the cache?

Comment: Did you put your javascript file in the body or in the head ?

Comment: What do you mean by "files are not loaded"? do you receive 4xx or 5xx answer from the server? Could you add a screenshot of the network tab of the developer tools of Chrome?

Comment: @Kornflexx Most of my JS files are in the head. All AngularJS files are at the bottom of the body.

Comment: @JulienBachmann It's a bit hard to give that screenshot as this requires a brand new installation of the application, as well as chrome, so it's quite time consuming. I'll try to do it the next time I do a reinstall of the computer, but it's not going to happen today or tomorrow.